# C# Google API Contact.SetPhoto

Tags: c#, google-api

The following code returns an error (403 Forbidden) when it tries to retrieve the contact.

```
Contact contact = cr.Retrieve<Contact>(contactURI);
```

I based this code on Google's Profiles API page. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/profiles/.  I would appreciate any feed back.

```
RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings("Add Profile Photo", "consumerKey", "consumerSecret", username, domain);
ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);

Uri contactURI = new Uri("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/" + domain + "/full/" + username);

Contact contact = cr.Retrieve<Contact>(contactURI);

Stream outStream = File.OpenRead("C:\\temp\\profilePic.jpg");

try
{
    cr.SetPhoto(contact, outStream);
}
catch (GDataVersionConflictException e)
{
    throw new Exception("Exception setting photo: " + e.Message);
}
```

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace "consumerKey" and "consumerSecret" in the RequestSettings constructor with the OAuth Consumer Key and Secret of your application.

The documentation for the Documents List API has a lot of details (and C# code) about authentication, it should be pretty easy to adapt to use the Contacts API instead.

Also, if you want to use OAuth 2.0 (recommended), check the complete sample included in the library: http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/oauth2_sample/oauth2demo.cs

Comment: Sorry I did not make my self clear.  I have those in the code I just took them out for posting.  Thanks for the complete sample link I will check it out and see if it helps.